# What is a element's reationship to its list

Tags: python

I have a list

```
myList=[1,2,3,4]
```

I want to access '1' (i.e the first element of `myList`).

`myList` is an instance of class/type `list` & has its own datamembers/attributes `[1,2,3,4]`

so some way I must be able to access '1' with reference to `myList` (instance)

```
>>>EG: myList.__datamemeber__.iteritems()
```

Note: I know I can do

```
>>>for i in myList:
```

**Edit**
Okay my doubt was

1) is `myList` an instance of class/type `list` ?

2) if so what is '1' ,'2' ... of  `myList` ?

**EDIT**

Okay so I was trying to read a CSV with DictReader

```
>>>reader = csv.DictReader(ifile)
```

now I want to know if 'reader' is empty

so I thought if I could get a element of DictReader & see if its null

I can get all the lines

```
>>>for line in reader:
```

**I want to know if 'reader' is empty.Also if I get an instance (like `reader`) can I get the elements of it.**

Comment: `myList[0]` didn't work?  `for i in myList` totally works.  What's your question?  What can't you do?  Do you have code that doesn't work or gets an error?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Why is this tagged [metaclasses]?

Comment: When you did `type(myList)` what did you see?

Comment: I can get all the lines with `for line in reader:`.  Correct.  What's your question?  Please be as clear as you can.  Please provide code that does not work or produces an error message or something concrete and specific.  We can't guess what problem you're having.  Please **update** the question to clarify what's broken in your code.

Comment: "I want to know if 'reader' is empty"?  What does this mean?  After `for line in reader`.  It will be empty.  Before `for line in reader` it will not be empty.  You never need to test for emptiness.  You just use the `for` loop.  Please post some code that does not work.  Please post an error message.  Please clarify what isn't working for you.

Comment: I know  'After for line in reader. It will be empty. Before for line in reader it will not be empty'.But what if ifile is empty file object.so will reader be empty then?one can always use 'for line in reader:' & then check if line is empty.But I don't want that.I want to know if 'reader' is empty just after its created using csv.DictReader()

Comment: "I want to know if 'reader' is empty just after its created using csv.DictReader()".  Why?  What will you do with this information?  Please open a new question focused on this one thing.  Please delete this question, since the title makes no sense, the edits are confusing and the comments are hard to read.  Please focus on explaining why you want to know -- in advance -- that the reader will be empty.  Please explain what kind of code you think you want to write.  Please provide *examples*.  Please be *specific*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to operate under the (wrong) assumption that CSV readers are lists or at least somwhat like lists (or, more generally, sequences). With lists, checking for emptiness is easy - generally, compare the length to 0; in Python the idiom is for collections the be falsy if they are empty (i.e. `if not items: # empty collection`).

But CSV readers aren't lists or even collections, they're iterators. Whether or not there is an element in an iterator is unknown (in fact, it doesn't matter - read on), you can only ask for the next element and either get that or an exception if there is no next element. The items may not even exist until you ask for them. Iterators don't have a notion of length.

If you absolutely positively need special logic to handle empty files, there *is* a (rather ugly) way to do it, although it forces you to have that empty file-logic and the processing in the same place.

1. Make a reader
2. `try` to get its first element and store it somewhere (say, `first_element`).
3. `except StopIteration:` (i.e. when you get the exception that indicated "no more elements"), the file is empty (respectively, the reader considers its empty).
4. If the `except` didn't trigger (that's a `else` clause on the `try`, see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)), you got the first element, can process it, then proceed to process everything else the reader yields in your casual `for` loop.

Alternatively to the code duplication implied in the last step, just make the loop go `for element in itertools.chain([first_element], reader)` (which first yields `first_element` and then passes on each element `reader` yields). Note that this has *some* overhead though (probably negible compared to the reader's parsing efforts and your own processing, but for the record...).

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but this is exactly the explanation I was looking for.Thank you.`To communicate your exact problem & to understand it properly requires skill`.

Answer (score 2):

A list is indexed by an integer. For example, to get to its first (in Python, at index 0) item:

```
>> myList[0]
1
```

You can use list's `index` method to find the index of the given value:

```
>> myList.index(1)
0
```

And you can iterate a list with `enumerate` to get both the index and the item:

```
for index, item in enumerate(myList):
  print "myList[%s] is %s" % (index, item)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know 'After for line in reader. It will be empty. Before for line in reader it will not be empty'.But what if ifile is empty file object.so will reader be empty then?one can always use 'for line in reader:' & then check if line is empty.But I don't want that.I want to know if 'reader' is empty just after its created using csv.DictReader()

```
haverows = False
reader = csv.DictReader(ifile)
# reader may or may not have rows
for row in reader:
    haverows = True
    # reader definately had a row.  here it is
    print row

if not haverows:
    # reader never had any rows.  oh well.
print 'done!'
# reader is now exhausted of all its rows.
```

Comment: I don't want to use `for loop`

Comment: @jibin.  hmm.. that seems arbitrary.  why did you open the file at all?

Answer (score 0):

'1', '2' etc, are *items* of the list, as opposed to *attributes* (that's python jargon, I would have called them *elements*). As pointed out above, you usually just grab them with

```
mylist[0]     # ... or whatever instead of 0
```

For other fancy stuff, you might find *mylist.index* is handy, or  even  *itemgetter* from operator package.  Depends on what you want really.

Comment: I don't think that Python advocates to call the elements of a list: items. Do you have a reference concerning this point ? For a list, I use the term 'element'. For me, 'item' has a more general sense and I would call item everything that is one of several 'things' in a set, a list, a group of attributes or anything else. That's my feeling.